# Rails Paperclip Install Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, paperclip

I want to use paperclip in my project. So I added this to my gem file:

```
gem 'paperclip'
```

If i now run bundle install i get the following error message:

```
Fetching http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git
remote: Counting objects: 5249, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2315/2315), done.
remote: Total 5249 (delta 3596), reused 4384 (delta 2817)
Receiving objects: 100% (5249/5249), 804.81 KiB | 215 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3596/3596), done.
error: unable to create file test/fixtures/question?mark.png (Invalid argument)
```

Does someone know how to fix this error?

P.S.: I get the same eror when running:

```
rails plugin install git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git
```

Comment: What's your paperclip and rails -v ?

Comment: rails (3.1.0), paperclip (2.4.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm having the same problem as you, i'm currently looking into the solution on this page: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/pull/621

edit: good news, everyone! this seems to have worked for me (i'm using Windows 7). tl;dr: save paperclip as a directory on your computer and refer to it in your gemfile. then use bundle install.

```
gem 'paperclip', :path => 'vendor/gems/paperclip'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try gem "paperclip", "~> 2.4.5" in your gemfile

Comment: That's what my next idea would be :)